# Logstash write Elasticsearch Index in the Future

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, mapping, logstash, logstash-configuration

We have this weird hacky workaround involving writing to an index that is dated in the future.

I'm trying to set up logstash in order to do this, but I'm not even sure if its possible.

```
                      elasticsearch {
                           index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
                  }
```

Is there a way to modify this to so that I simultaneously write to an index that is also 7 days in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a second elasticsearch{} output stanza, using an index with a future date.  To generate the date, drop into the ruby{} filter and add 7 days to @timestamp.

Comment: I don't think this solves my issue because I'm not trying to modify a field, I'm trying to get it to write to an index in the fugure which is passed by index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}". However, since it its a string, I'm not quite sure how to add 7 days to that particular value.

Comment: "drop into the ruby{} filter and add 7 days to @timestamp".  @timestamp isn't a string, it's a datetime.  Try googling: "ruby add days to datetime".  You can create a new logstash field in ruby and then use that in your second elasticsearch output stanza.